# how to enable the PAT token in databricks for users under a azure group through terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, databricks, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-azure

I want to add the configs to the databricks account to enable PAT token generation for certain time for all nonadmin users which are part of a azure group.

But I dont find the settings to enable this in terraform.

I see this documentation but it does have any config for PAT token. [Databricks in azure](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/databricks_workspace)

Then I also see this config, this does speak about PAT token config but how to link it to the databricks workspace I created and how to give assignment to a specific azure user group. [Enable PAT token in databricks](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/workspace_conf)

---

From the answers, I wrote below code to give token use access for users, but it threw errors.
Terraform code :

```
    terraform {
  required_providers {
    databricks = {
      source = "databricks/databricks"
      version = "1.21.0"
    }
    azurerm = {
      version = ">=3.2.1"
    }
  }
}



provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

provider "databricks" {
  azure_workspace_resource_id = azurerm_databricks_workspace.myworkspace.id
  auth_type = "azure-client-secret"
}

provider "null" {}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "myresourcegroup" {
  name     = "samghj2-myresourcegroup"
  location = "centralus"
}

resource "azurerm_databricks_workspace" "myworkspace" {
  location                      = azurerm_resource_group.myresourcegroup.location
  name                          = "samghj2-workspace"
  resource_group_name           = azurerm_resource_group.myresourcegroup.name
  sku                           = "trial"

}



resource "databricks_workspace_conf" "config_map" {
  custom_config = {
    "maxTokenLifetimeDays" : "1",
    "enableTokensConfig" : true
  }
  depends_on                          = [azurerm_databricks_workspace.myworkspace]

}

resource "databricks_permissions" "token_usage" {
  authorization = "tokens"

  access_control {
    group_name       = "users"
    permission_level = "CAN_USE"
  }

  depends_on                          = [azurerm_databricks_workspace.myworkspace]
}
```

The error which I get :

```
│ Error: cannot create permissions: tokens tokens does not exist
│ 
│   with databricks_permissions.token_usage,
│   on main.tf line 51, in resource "databricks_permissions" "token_usage":
│   51: resource "databricks_permissions" "token_usage" {
```

---

edit 3 :
it seems there is a an requirement where an admin needs to create a token first before he can enable users to create their own token. This doesnt make any sense to me. I want to know more about it. Tracking this qsn here -> [why we need to create a token before applying Token permissions in databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77730282/why-we-need-to-create-a-token-before-applying-token-permissions-in-databricks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two separate Terraform resources, one is [`databricks_workspace_conf`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/workspace_conf) to enable tokens at workspace level:

```
resource "databricks_workspace_conf" "this" {
  custom_config = {
    "enableTokensConfig": true
  }
}
```

Other - [`databricks_permissions`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/permissions#token-usage) - to grant CAN USE permission for specific group:

```
resource "databricks_permissions" "token_usage" {
  authorization = "tokens"

  access_control {
    group_name       = "users"
    permission_level = "CAN_USE"
  }
}
```

Comment: enableIpAccessLists -> enableTokensConfig

Comment: @Kombajn how do you figure out this,, I will try it out and post an update on the solution but I am really curious how do you navigate in the terraform documentation to find this out. Searching in the databricks docs provided by hashicorp terraform, I could not find this data. How can I too acquire this knowledge?

Comment: I get below error while using this -> Exception: AzureTaskRetriableException: [TerraformCreate]: Failed to execute terraform. Reason: Terraform Execution Exception. Reason: Expected exit code 0, doesn't match with the execution exit code 1 for the command: [/opt/homebrew/bin/terraform, apply, -auto-approve, -no-color, -lock=false]. Error Message: --Error: cannot create permissions: tokens tokens does not exist----  with module.jterraform.databricks_permissions.token_usage,--  on .terraform/modules/jterraform/main.tf line 202, in resource "databricks_permissions" "token_usage":-- 202: resourc

Comment: `permissions: tokens tokens does not exist` - this suggests some typo, double check, also try running with debug on. As for figuring that out, I guess it's just experience, I've been working a lot with the provider and possibly just read the docs in full a few times already.

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy i have provided my code in the edit. its not a typo issue. I have literally spend hours in figuring this out but no luck. Can you please take a look.

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy it seems there is a weird requirement of creating a token first, before you apply an policy. This doesnot make any sense to me. I raised another qsn here to know more about it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77730282/why-we-need-to-create-a-token-before-applying-token-permissions-in-databricks

Comment: That's super weird, but as I checked I indeed have also a token in my Terraform config (with [databricks_token](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/token)) - probably that's why it worked for me straight away.