# why we need to create a token before applying Token permissions in databricks

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, personal-access-token

We want to enable the access for the users to create token.

Now, I have logged in to the databricks account using the admin access, and I go to "Access Control" -> "Personal Access Tokens" and I want to enable the access to the users so that they can create token. But I see that button to enable the settings is disabled and it shows a msg on hovering that "Token permissions can be set only if at least one token has been created in the workspace."

[image]

Now, my question is why this sort of pre-condition is added. When all I have to do is enable my users to be able to use token, then why do I need to create a token first which is of no use.

Is this a bug or a desired functionality. If yes, then whats the reason behind it.

Comment: Yes, that is due to **Testing and Verification** of tokens.

Before allowing token creation for other users, the system want to confirm that the token creation process functions properly. By requiring the creation of at least one token, it ensures that the system has been tested and operates as anticipated.

Initially, it will ask you to create the token. Afterwards, even if you revoke the token, you can still use **Permission Settings**.

Comment: That's like 'Allow unrestricted cluster creation' grant possible only after creating at least one cluster - because you need to test that it works :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is due to **Testing and Verification** of tokens.

Before allowing token creation for other users, the system want to confirm that the token creation process functions properly. By requiring the creation of at least one token, it ensures that the system has been tested and operates as anticipated.

Initially, it will ask you to create the token. Afterwards, even if you revoke the token, you can still use **Permission Settings**.

Answer (score 0):

There might be quite a few reasons for this,the requirement to create at least one token before enabling token permissions is mostly for a design choice to ensure that the token creation process is functional, trackable for auditing purposes. it can make sure that only authorized admin user with enough privileges are enabling token permissions as a security measure.